# How to create a font outline in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, text, outline

I'm very new to python and coding in general and I'm just learning and trying out Tkinter. I know some basics, but is there any way to achieve an outline of the text widget? What code would I use.

What i want:
[image: what i want]

What my output looks like:
[image: what my output looks like]

My current code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x1000")
root.title("Feud with Friends")

qLbl = Label(root)
qLbl["text"] = ("Feud With Friends™")
qLbl["font"] = ("marlon regular", 46)
qLbl.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=E, columnspan=6, padx=130, pady=50)
qLbl.config(fg='moccasin')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hiya.  It's always worth checking the site's search function before asking a question.  [This SO answer might be what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37143560/4746328).

Answer (score 0):

```
qLbl = Label(root, borderwidth=1, relief="raised", text="Feud With Friends™")
qLbl["font"] = (fontA, fontSizeA)
qLbl.grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=E, columnspan=6, padx = 130, pady = 50)
qLbl.config(fg='moccasin')
```

I suppose this will help!

Comment: Hi, so I tried your code - I didn't clarify properly in the question, mb, but how would you make an outline for the text, not the widget itself. The code you gave only seems to make a outline of the box.